# checking if session exist on another website

Tags: php, ajax, cross-domain

I have a PHP project which has its multiple subdomains(a.domainone.com, b.domainone.com, c.domainone.com) hosted on another server and another main domain domaintwo.com on another server.

Aim: User can access subdomains of first domain only if user has logged in domaintwo.com domain.

Movement of user: A user visits on  a.domainone.com > user is asked to clicked enter now > enter now has a ajax function to check user is logged into domaintwo.com or not (responses as needlogin or logindone) > if not a popup of domaintwo opens, on success login it closes echoing: loggin succesfull go ahead and hit enter now

Problem: After loggin it when user hits enter > same popup opens > echos login already done (hav put validation to check if session exist already) > so when checked echoing session varible found its blank on a.subdomain.com but when go to directly on the php page of domaintwo.com login handler it echos the value of session varibale correctly.

So I checked, the ajax response is always 'needlogin' ....!!!

Just an idea would be appreciating.

Thanks & Regards

### Edit

I have already done 
        < ? php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ? > 
in domaintwo.com otherwise i would not be receiving even the response of if session as 'needLogin' in ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need the session_id from the session cookie on the browser.  Fortunately (unforturately for you) a client browser will not allow access to cookies from a different domain.  Since you can't get the session cookie, you can't get the session id, so there is no way to grab session across domains.

If both sites are on the same server, and you have direct access to the session store, and you're not regenerating session id's, you might do something shady like reading the session_id on one site and pass it in the get parameters to the next site, then manually open the session file based on the id and read it...

Comment: But don't facebook like btn clicking does same?? it checks if user is logged in fb or not and only then it allows liking it. Any idea what they use to get it, if its not session ??

Comment: @luckycool They use Oauth and 3rd party cookies.  Your site has an application on facebook an you talk to that application to get the facebook data.  When a user likes something, the like is sent to facebook, then you site info from facebook not the client.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need an idea about what's going on: You are accessing data from another domain, so the cross domain policy of web browsers kicks in.

You can start your research on Wikipedia:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Hi Shi, thanks but I know about the origin policy and I hv already implemented the <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?> on domaintwo.com.